# Is there a program that will prevent changing the numlock state?

Tags: windows

I use my numeric keypad for its intended purpose: entering numbers. My boss, on the other hand, doesn't believe in the arrow keys (or something), so whenever he uses my computer, he turns off my numlock.

I find this quite annoying (<--understatement), and I've often wondered if there was a way to either prevent him from messing with my keyboard settings, or resetting it after a period of time, or something. Even a simple confirmation message (*"Are you sure you want to misappropriate the numeric keypad? Do you know that there's a perfectly serviceable delete key just a little bit to the left?*") would help.

Is there a program that will do this? (OS is Windows XP, at least for now; might be Windows 7 in a few weeks.) Failing that, is there some place that sells a gadget that will give my boss an electric shock if he touches my numlock key?

Comment: This does raise the question of why your boss uses your computer. Hasn't he got one of his own?

Comment: First question that sprang to mind here also ...

Comment: He has multiple computers of his own, but sometimes when we're discussing a question, he wants to "drive". I've learned never to argue with men about things like that, it's not worth it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoHotKey?

```
SetNumlockState, AlwaysOn
```

would lock the numlock.

edit: You may also consider

```
Numlock::MsgBox, [your message here]
```

or

```
numlock::shift
```

to map it to shift - allowing you to hold down the key and use it as arrow keys, or not hold the key, and use it for numbers.

Comment: Why use a perfectly good go-kart wheel when you can use a tank tread? ;) +1

Comment: You think anybody's gonna argue with a tank? :P

Comment: Um, I'm afraid you've lost me. Is AutoHotKey a program? If so, where can I find it? What else does it do? *Some* context would be appreciated...

Comment: www.autohotkey.com is the program. It's a computer automation program with a lovely scripting language. Place that inside a script (a text file with the extension `.ahk`), and run it, and your numlock key will be strangely... unresponsive. You could use something like `Numlock::MsgBox, You're using the gorram keyboard wrong` to show a messagebox instead. It's a lovely program, I highly reccomend it for almost any task ;)

Comment: Actually, playing around with it: `numlock::shift` remaps numlock to shift. When you hold shift and numlock is on, **the keys behave as if it is off**, so both you and your boss can be happy, just he'll have to hold the key down while pressing it.

Comment: Holding down shift always 'shifts' the numeric keypad, it's not a result of remapping the numlock key. And if training my boss were a possibility, I wouldn't be spending idle moments plotting things like this. :)

Comment: Oh, I realise it's not because if the remapping, but if you DO remap it, it makes it much easier! If training your boss isn't an option, the messagebox should do fine :) (Or `run, shutdown.exe -t 30 -f -s -c "Don't do that"` :P)

Comment: (I just checked out the website) Ooooh, this is an evil, evil program... in all the best senses of the word, of course. :) Can you suggest a script that will allow turning off numlock, but will turn it back on after a period of time? (Is such a thing even possible? I.e. have the numlock key trigger an action, but delay that action?)

Comment: Sure, check out `SetTimer`, or `while` in the (fantastic) help file. SetTimer starts a repeating routine, BUT you can use negative numbers to make it run only once. `Numlock::SetTimer label -1000`, for example, would run routine "label" after 10 seconds, only once. Have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) to remap numlock to some other key, like shift.

Comment: If you hunt around the web, you can also find the appropriate registry values to set to do the same thing - SharpKeys is better interface to the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard`.

The entry `InitialKeyboardIndicators` can have the following values:

0 = NumLock is turned OFF after the logon.
1 = Disable NumLock.
2 = Numlock is turned ON after  the logon.

**EDIT**

If I understand your dilemma correctly, you like one NumLock setting and your boss likes another. So why don't you create another user account for your boss? You can also use a screen-saver with your password, to force him to logon in order to use the computer. I believe that's a better solution than monkeying with the registry.

Regarding the registry key, there are actually two of those. Here's how it works:

After boot and before login, Windows reads 
`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators` 
and sets it up as default. After Logon, Windows Applies the setting from 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators` (0=Off, 2=On).
This setting is stored independently inside each user profile, and the state from the Windows Session is saved at logoff. This means if you turn your NumLock on, a value of 2 is written at logoff, and NumLock will be toggled on at next login.

Comment: +1, though logging in and out is likely to be a bit of unnecessary hassle

Comment: Doesn't this only affect the *initial* numlock state, though? I.e. how it's set when you log on, but after that you can toggle it at will?

Comment: Oh, wait, I just saw the 'Disable NumLock' bit. Unfortunately, that sounds like just the opposite of what I want - wouldn't that simply disable the numeric keypad?